# How to load ALKIS (GML3) data in GeoTools

Tags: geotools, gml

I wonder how I can load ALKIS GML (German gov geo data) in GeoTools.

Here is a small sample dataset from the government: http://www.schleswig-holstein.de/LVERMGEOSH/DE/Service/Download/Testdaten/alkis_bestandsdaten_etrs89zip__blob=publicationFile.zip

I put together some simple code to load it:

```
    GML gml = new GML(Version.GML3);
    CRSAuthorityFactory crsFac = ReferencingFactoryFinder.getCRSAuthorityFactory("EPSG", null);
    CoordinateReferenceSystem osgbCrs;

    try {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream("/home/me/Bestandsdatenauszug_NAS_ETRS89_UTM_0348.xml");
        osgbCrs = crsFac.createCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:25832");
        gml.setCoordinateReferenceSystem(osgbCrs);

        FeatureCollection fc = gml.decodeFeatureCollection(in);
        System.out.println("size: "+fc.size());
    } ...
```

But sadly I get the following errors:

```
WARNING  Error parsing: NAS-Operationen.xsd
WARNING  Could not find a schema
```

As I am sure the file itself is valid and well-tested, what is going wrong here? How can I successfully load this file?

Comment: Do you have that schema? Or know where it is?

Comment: It should be http://www.adv-online.de/AAA-Modell/Dokumente-der-GeoInfoDok/GeoInfoDok-6-0/binarywriterservlet?imgUid=b2c23fd2-1153-911a-3b21-718a438ad1b2&uBasVariant=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111&isDownload=true (direct link to ZIP). I already tried putting those files into the same directory and serving them from localhost.

Comment: I got a bit closer now, I had to unpack the ZIP so that NAS-Operationen.xsd is right inside my workspace. Now I am getting a NullPointerException from fc.size() though and cannot figure out why.